# How to create a text mask in Excel 2007

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers:
59046
64940
77505
101409
140331
1036135
3166909

I want every number to be exectly 9 digits.
For example, i want 59046 as 000059046, 1036135 as 001036135.
How can i create a mask for the input?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want every number to be exectly 9 digits.

> For example, I want 59046 as 000059046, 1036135 as 001036135. How can I create a mask for the input?

This can be achieved with a custom number format that consists of 9 zeros `000000000`

---

#### Fixed-length Numbers

> When you want to display leading zeros for a fixed-length number,
>   create a custom format with the same number of zeros (0) as digits
>   that you want to display.
>
> For example, if you want to display a fixed-length number with five
>   digits, create a custom number format with five zeros.
>
> Use the 00000 format to display a number with five digits. When you
>   use this format, the numbers that you type and the numbers that
>   Microsoft Excel displays are listed in the following table.
>
> ```
>    Typed number    Displayed number
>    --------------------------------
>    28217           28217
>    1234            01234
> ```

Source [Using a custom number format to display leading zeros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/81518)